# CSSでのtable要素の余白

Tags: html, css

HPでのナビゲーションとして、画像を横に５つ並べて表示させたいと考え、tableを使って画像を
配置したのですが、table全体の外側の余白が残ってしまいます。

merginを使う方法（http://hmaster.net/ctable4.html）などを調べてやってみましたが、余白は消えません。

余白を消す方法について、どなたかご教授いただければ幸いです。

HTMLのコード

```
<div class="menu">
   <ul>
    <li class="menu-item"><img src="nav21.png" id="img2"></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><img src="nav22.png" id="img3"></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><img src="nav23.png" id="img4"></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><img src="nav24.png" id="img5"></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><img src="nav25.png" id="img6"></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
```

CSSのコード

```
.menu{
 margin-right: 10px;
 position: fixed;
 margin: 0px;
 list-style: none;
 background-color: #010101;
 filter:alpha(opacity=80);
 -moz-opacity: 0.8;
 opacity: 0.8;
 left: 0;
 right: 0px;
 z-index: 3;
 bottom: 0px;;
 overflow: hidden;
 display: table;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
 padding:0;
}

.menu-item{
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: bottom;
 border-left:1px solid #ffffff;
}

.menu-item li{
 float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ul` に対してマージン・パディングを０にしてみてはどうでしょうか？

例：

```
.menu ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ul自体に`display:table;`としていなくて親のdivがtableになっていますね。
`.menu-item li`というのも、liの中のliということになってしまいます。
それに、`table-cell`で横並びにしたのなら`float:left;`は不要ですよね。
要素の階層構造とセレクタの書き方が合っていないように思います。

どこかでスタイルを指定済みであれば、marginやpaddingの上書きが必要ですね。

何もしていなければこのようになるはずです。
http://codepen.io/mayo31/pen/bZrPEA

```css
.menu {
  background: #336699;
}

.menu ul {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.menu-item {
  display: table-cell;
  border-left:1px solid #ffffff;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="menu-item"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random" id="img2"></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random" id="img3"></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random" id="img4"></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random" id="img5"></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random" id="img6"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```